# Codeigniter - Last row in Model

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, codeigniter-3

I have 3 packages such as Silver, Gold, Platinum. I have to show last row of these package in Package View. I create any Model page for this, but this code only show last one row of one last item from table. For example, I have 3 packages, It only shows last package of one package. Not show other packages such as Gold and Silver. I want to show last edited package with other packages. If I edit any package, I want to show last row of last edited package with other packages. How I can do it?

My Model Code:

```
public function packages()

    {

        $this->db->select('

        package.*, packageService.*

        ');

        $this->db->from('packageService');

        $this->db->join('package', ' package.packageService = packageService.packageServiceId');

        $this->db->limit(1);

        $this->db->order_by('packageId',"DESC");

        $query = $this->db->get();

        $results = $query->result();

        return $results;

    }
```

My Package View:

```
<section id="main-content">
    <section class="wrapper site-min-height">
        <!-- page start-->
        <div class="row">
            <!--price start-->
            <div class="text-center feature-head">
                <h1> PACKAGES </h1>
                <p>Choose Your Special Package Plan. </p>
            </div>
            <?php foreach($packs as $get) { ?>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
                    <div class="pricing-table <?php if ($get->packageNameEn == 'Platinum') { echo 'most-popular'; } ?>">
                        <div class="pricing-head">
                            <h1> <?php echo $get->packageNameEn; ?> </h1>
                            <h5><del>€ <?php echo $get->packagePrice ?></del></h5>
                            <h2><span class="note">€</span> <?php echo $get->packagePriceCut ?> </h2>

                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <?php echo $get->packageServiceNameEn ?>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="price-actions">
                            <a class="btn" href="javascript:;">Get Now</a>
                            <a class="btn" href="<?php echo base_url("package/edit/$get->packageId"); ?>">Edit</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <!-- page end-->
    </section>
</section>
<!--main content end-->
```

Comment: you need to add last_modify_date column into packageService table, and then order by this column DESC

Comment: I already have edited date in package table. packageEditDate.

Comment: add the table structure and please explain a little bit more what you want to obtain, is ambiguous

Comment: I explain that I want to show 3 packages or I can add new packages in next time, anyway, I want to show last edited package of these packages. Is it clearly?

Comment: yes, now is OK. Thank you.

Comment: How can I do this? Can you help me for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177136/discussion-between-vasilenicusor-and-khaoscrea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to change the `packageRev` to `packageParent` with default 0. In this field we keep the reference to original package ID.
Then in your model

```
$this->db->select_max('packageId', 'MaxPackageId'); 
$this->db->select('IF(packageParent = 0 , packageId, packageParent) as parent', FALSE); 
$this->db->from('package'); 
$this->db->group_by('parent'); 

$subquery = $this->db->get_compiled_select(); 
$this->db->reset_query();
$this->db->select('package.*, packageService.*'); 
$this->db->from('package'); 
$this->db->join("($subquery) t1","t1.MaxPackageId = package.packageId"); 
$this->db->join('packageService', 'package.packageId = packageService.packageServiceId', 'LEFT');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Also you need to update your controller according to this

Comment: Come to chat ? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177136/discussion-between-vasilenicusor-and-khaoscrea